# Is there an easier way to do this ? php navigation menu if(isset($_GET['counter'])){ include('counter.php');}

Tags: php, html

This is my php navigation menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Projects</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript.php?counter">Counter App</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?randomnumber">Random Number Generator</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?hexgenerator">Color Generator</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?popup">Pop Up</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?accordion">Accordion</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?hiddensearch">Hidden Search</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?blurryloading">Blurry Loading</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?scrolleffect">Scroll Effect</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?palindrome">Palindrome</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['counter'])){
  include('counter.php');
}if(isset($_GET['randomnumber'])){
  include('randomnumber.php');
}if(isset($_GET['hexgenerator'])){
  include('hexgenerator.php');
}if(isset($_GET['popup'])){
  include('modalpopup.php');
}if(isset($_GET['accordion'])){
  include('accordion1.php');
}if(isset($_GET['hiddensearch'])){
  include('hiddensearch.php');
}if(isset($_GET['blurryloading'])){
  include('blurryloading.php');
}if(isset($_GET['scrolleffect'])){
  include('blurryloading.php');
}if(isset($_GET['scrolleffect'])){
  include('ScrollAnimation.php');
}if(isset($_GET['palindrome'])){
  include('palindrome.php');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This should be self explanatory on what I am trying to do here. I am tired of having to constantly put if statements for each time something is clicked. Somebody please direct me to an easier way to do this.

Comment: Have an associative array whose key is the parameter value and value is the file name

Comment: Or make all parameter values exactly match the filename (minus extension) and then append .php to it

Comment: Also instead of a different parameter name for each page, just use one name and change its value - e.g. `javascript.php?page=counter`. Much easier to make php only check one name. What you're doing now (multiple parameter names but none of them having values) isn't really how it's intended to be used

Comment: P.s. as an aside, why is your file named javascript.php? It doesn't seem to use any javascript!

Comment: Look at `<title>`. It's a list of projects related to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the applications in an array. You can use this array to create all the `<li>`, then check it in your `if` statement.

I've changed the URL to use a specific parameter name for all the pages, as suggested by @ADyson.

```
<?php
$apps = [
    "counter" => "Counter App",
    "randomnumber" => "Random Number Generator",
    "hexgenerator" => "Color Generator",
    "popup" => "Pop Up",
    "accordion" => "Accordion",
    "hiddensearch" => "Hidden Search",
    "blurryloading" => "Blurry Loading",
    "scrolleffect" => "Scroll Effect",
    "palindrome" => "Palindrome"
];
?>
    <ul>
<?php
foreach ($apps as $key => $name) { ?>
    <li><a href="javascript.php?page=<?= $key ?>"><?= $name ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? null;
if (isset($apps[$page])) {
    include("$page.php");
}
?>
```